# getResponseText method of PromptResponse object not found

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm making a very simple function for a Google Spreadsheet that asks the user for a value and write it down in a cell.
The usual way to do it seems to use `ui.prompt` and then to get the content with the `getResponse` method.
However the `getResponse` method used on a `PromptResponse` object throws a 'method not found error' in my code.
Do you know what is the way to get the text from a prompt ?

```
function addFoodstuff(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Carrefour");
  var ncol=findTemp();
  var tempHead = sh.getRange(1,ncol);
  var firstEmpty =tempHead.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).offset(1,0);

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ans = [[ui.prompt("Entrez un aliment")]];
  var txt =ans.getResponseText();
  firstEmpty.setValues(txt);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

As the error message states, the method could not be found, which should point you to the object you are calling this method on. In your case it is written into an `ans` variable, which is an instance of `Array` (be it a 2-dimensional one, though). Method `getResponseText()` is only available on `PromptResponse` class instances.

**Solution**

Beware of the order in which you modify your objects. When you wrapped your `ui.prompt('yourText')` in brackets, you made a conversion to an `Array`. Thus, you should extract the response text first (and ideally, don't override the variable just in case you might need this `PromptResponse` instance later).

**Sample**

```
function addFoodstuff(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Carrefour");
  var ncol=findTemp();
  var tempHead = sh.getRange(1,ncol);
  var firstEmpty =tempHead.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).offset(1,0);

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var answer = ui.prompt("Entrez un aliment"); //keep it unchanged;
  var txt =answer.getResponseText();
  var values = [[txt]];

  firstEmpty.setValues(values);
}
```

**Useful links**

1. `Array` built-in object [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array);
2. `PromptResponse` class [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/prompt-response);